# How do I work with days and months in Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby, date, activerecord

I have the date when an article was created in a DB table. I have articles since the August until today.

I tried to create a SQL query, in ActiveRecord, to get the articles that were created today.

For example, today is the 14th of January and I tried to get those articles that were created on the 14th of August, 14th of September until today.

I tried something like this:

```
today = Date.today
day = today.strftime('%d')
day_next = (today + 1.day).strftime('%d')

Article.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', day, day_next) #day = 14, day_next = 15
```

But this doesn't return the right statement, because articles were released on the 14th of December and the 14th of October. This query returns me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this. Assuming `created_at` is a normal datetime/timestamp field you should just convert `created_at` to its day using `DAY()` and then compare it directly to a normal Ruby Date object.

```
day = Date.today

Article.where 'DAY( created_at ) = DAY( ? )', day

# or just...

Article.where 'DAY( created_at ) = DAY( CURRENT_DATE() )'
```

(Misread your question originally; answer updated.)

Comment: but this return me only the articles, that were released only in one day (eg. 2012-01-14) - but I would like to get all articles, that were released 14th day of the each month

Comment: right initial reasoning but OP wants " I try to get those articles, that were created in 14th August, 14th September ... til today." not just on one day (through the q is confusing).

Comment: checked as correct however this would also get 'the 14' from 2 years ago, 10 yers ago, etc.

Comment: Ah, the question indeed unclear. Simply add an additional condition to the `WHERE` clause along the lines of `AND DATE( created_at ) >= ?`.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I know and I need it this way.

Comment: @Jorda this way works pretty nice on MySQL database, but not at PostgreSQL. I tried to edit this query to the PostgreSQL's shape - `Article.where 'DATE_PART("day", created_at ) = DATE_PART("day", ?)', day` but this unfortunately doesn't works... where's the trick?

Comment: I'm not sure, @user984621, as I don't have a Postgres server handy and it's not my strong suit. Certainly your code seems like what I would try. What do you get if you `SELECT` those values?